# The correct way to include registry, custom message and code files using Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

This might sound like a stupid question. At the moment I have created three files:

1. `AutoBackupSettingsPage`
2. `AutoBackupSettingsPage_CustomMessages`
3. `AutoBackupSettingsPage_Registry`

The first file has a `[Code]` section at the top, followed by the handlers and custom page for my Automatic Backups feature.

The second file file has a `[CustomMessages]` section at the top followed by all the appropriate custom messages.

The third file has a `[Registry]` section at the top followed by all the registry key definitions.

At the moment, I am using `#include` like this (code snipped):

```pascal
[Registry]
#include ".\AutoBackupSettingsPage_Registry.iss"

[CustomMessages]
#include ".\AutoBackupSettingsPage_CustomMessages.iss"

[Code]
program Setup;

{ global variables }
var
  bIsUpgrading: Boolean;
  dotnetRedistPath: string;
  dotNetNeeded: boolean;
  bDownloadHelpDocSetup: boolean;
  vcRedist64BitPath: string;
  vcRedist32BitPath: string;
  bVcRedist64BitNeeded : boolean;
  bVcRedist32BitNeeded : boolean;
  bSelectTasksVisited: Boolean;

{ Download Wizard Form plugin }
#define DwinsHs_Use_Predefined_Downloading_WizardPage
#define DwinsHs_Data_Buffer_Length 65536
#define DwinsHs_Auto_Continue
#include ".\dwinshs\dwinshs.iss"

{ Auto Backup Settings Page }
#include ".\AutoBackupSettingsPage.iss"

{ Import the LoadVCLStyle function from VclStylesInno.DLL }
procedure LoadVCLStyle(VClStyleFile: String); external 'LoadVCLStyleW@files:VclStylesInno.dll stdcall setuponly';
procedure LoadVCLStyle_UnInstall(VClStyleFile: String); external 'LoadVCLStyleW@{%TEMP}\VclStylesInno.dll stdcall uninstallonly delayload';
```

Initially I wanted to have all the files together in one but then I came to the conclusion that it would be wrong to insert `Registry` and `CustomMessages` sections after the start of the `Code` section and it would confuse the system. So I kept things simple by having distinct files and including each in the right section.

Is this the right way to do this kind of thing with Inno Setup?

---

To make this clear, this is how it would be in context with my master ISS file:

- `[Setup]`
- `[Tasks]`
- `[Files]`
- `[Icons]`
- `[Run]`
- `[UninstallRun]`
- `[_istool]`
- `[Registry]`
- `[UninstallDelete]`
- `[InstallDelete]`
- `[Languages]`
- `[CustomMessages]`
- `[Dirs]`
- `[Thirdparty]`
- `[Code]`
- `[CustomMessages]` #
- `[Registry]` #
- `[Code]` #
- `[Code]`

The ones with the `#` character would be the single `#include` file. Did not know if it would be considered bad design to break the `code` section like that or not?

---

For arguments sake, take these little chunks. They just convey the idea of what is happening when you `#include` a file slap bang in the middle of the `[Code]` section:

```
; Contents before here in master
; ...
; ...
[Code]
program Setup;

{ global variables }
var
  bIsUpgrading: Boolean;
  dotnetRedistPath: string;
  dotNetNeeded: boolean;
  bDownloadHelpDocSetup: boolean;
  vcRedist64BitPath: string;
  vcRedist32BitPath: string;
  bVcRedist64BitNeeded : boolean;
  bVcRedist32BitNeeded : boolean;
  bSelectTasksVisited: Boolean;

; =================================
; Start of included file

[Registry]
; 32 Bit
Root: "HKLM"; \
    Subkey: "Software\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\Options"; \
    ValueType: dword; \
    ValueName: "BackupAtShutdownWhat"; \
    ValueData: "{code:GetWhatToBackupMode|0}"; \
    Flags: uninsdeletevalue; \
    Check: IsNewInstall

Root: "HKLM"; \
    Subkey: "Software\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\Options"; \
    ValueType: dword; \
    ValueName: "BackupAtShutdownMode"; \
    ValueData: "{code:GetHowToBackupMode|0}"; \
    Flags: uninsdeletevalue; \
    Check: IsNewInstall

[CustomMessages]
pageAutoBackupTitle=Automatic Backup
pageAutoBackupDescription=Configure automatic backup settings.
lblBackupWhat=What to backup:
radBackupWhatNone=Don't perform any backup when the program shuts down
radBackupWhatComplete=Make a complete backup when the program shuts down
radBackupWhatEssential=Only make an essential backup when the program shuts down
lblBackupMode=How to backup:
radBackupModeAuto=Perform automatically when the program is shut down
radBackupModeManual=Prompt the user when the program is shut down
lblPromptMode=Also prompt to backup at the following intervals while the application is running:
cmbPromptModeItemNever=Never prompt to backup
cmbPromptModeItemDaily=Prompt to backup everyday
cmbPromptModeItemWeekly=Prompt to backup once a week
cmbPromptModeItemMonthly=Prompt to backup once a month
lblBackupFolder=Where to backup:


[Code]

{ Constants }
const
  BackupWhat_None = 0;
  BackupWhat_Complete = 1;
  BackupWhat_Essential = 2;

    BackupMode_Automatic = 0;
  BackupMode_Manual = 1;

    BackupPrompt_Never = 0;
    BackupPrompt_Daily = 1;
    BackupPrompt_Weekly = 2;
    BackupPrompt_Monthly = 3;

{ Global Variables }
var
  pageAutoBackup: TWizardPage;
  pnlBackupWhat: TPanel;
  lblBackupWhat: TLabel;
  radBackupWhatNone: TNewRadioButton;
  radBackupWhatComplete: TNewRadioButton;
  radBackupWhatEssential: TNewRadioButton;
  lblBackupMode: TLabel;
  pnlBackupMode: TPanel;
  radBackupModeAuto: TNewRadioButton;
  radBackupModeManual: TNewRadioButton;
  lblPromptMode: TLabel;
  cmbPromptMode: TNewComboBox;
  lblBackupFolder: TLabel;
  txtBackupFolder: TNewEdit;
  btnSelectBackupFolder: TNewButton;

;====================================
; Now the master continues with the code:

{ Import the LoadVCLStyle function from VclStylesInno.DLL }
procedure LoadVCLStyle(VClStyleFile: String); external 'LoadVCLStyleW@files:VclStylesInno.dll stdcall setuponly';
procedure LoadVCLStyle_UnInstall(VClStyleFile: String); external 'LoadVCLStyleW@{%TEMP}\VclStylesInno.dll stdcall uninstallonly delayload';

{ Import the UnLoadVCLStyles function from VclStylesInno.DLL }
procedure UnLoadVCLStyles; external 'UnLoadVCLStyles@files:VclStylesInno.dll stdcall setuponly';
procedure UnLoadVCLStyles_UnInstall; external 'UnLoadVCLStyles@{app}\VclStylesInno.dll stdcall uninstallonly';

{ Importing ShowWindow Windows API from User32.DLL }
function ShowWindow(hWnd: Integer; uType: Integer): Integer; external 'ShowWindow@user32.dll stdcall';

const
  { Changed to 4.6.2 download link (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#redist) }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I can't say it any clearer. In the master file we start a `[code]` section  with some public variables etc. Then (because of a `#include` it suddendly goes to a `[registry]` section, then a `[custommessages]` section, then a `[code]` section and finally returns back to the original master file `[code]` section. It is acceptable that the registry / custom messages sections have been injected into the middle of the code section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inno Setup does not care about the order of the sections. You can even split the sections into parts and mix the parts any way you like.

The rest is just a matter of your coding style and personal preferences.

Comment: Understood. It is a catch 22. My personal style is that I have one included file, thus making it modular. But my OCD tells me I know it looks bad with the sections fractured. Oh well! Thanks for confirming.